# Instantiate Subclasses from Static Methods

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I'm think perhaps there is not a way to do this, but I thought it worth asking. I want to do something like the following:

```
public class Super {
    public static String print() { System.out.println(new Super().getClass().getSimpleName()); }
    public Super() {}
}

public class Subclass extends Super {
    public Subclass() {}

    public void main(String[] args) {
        Super.print();
        Subclass.print();
    }
}
```

My hope is to get the Super.print() to show "Super" and Subclass.print() to show "Subclass". I don't see how to do this from a static context however. Thanks for the help.

I'm well aware that I can do this without static methods, and that I can pass a class into each method call. I don't want to do that as that requires redefining several static methods on many subclasses.

Comment: You might want to have Subclass extend Super so it can call print() and have print() return a string or change its signature to void...just an FYI.

Comment: I added the extends Super to my example. I had originally intended to put it there and forgot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply define a separate `Subclass.print()` method with the desired implementation. Static methods are class scoped, so every subclass can have its own implementation.

```
public class Subclass {
    public Subclass() {}
    public static String print() {
        System.out.println(Subclass.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        Super.print();
        Subclass.print();
    }
}
```

Note that your code can be somewhat simplified - `Super.class` suffices instead of `new Super().getClass()`.

Also note, that static methods are *not* polymorphic - `Super.print()` and `Subclass.print()` will always call the method in the respective class. This is why they are bound to a class, not an object.

If you have a large class hierarchy, you may end up with a lot of duplicated code by implementing a separate static `print()` in each. Instead, you could define a single non-static method to do the job:

```
public abstract class Super {
    public final String print() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that this method does not even need to be polymorphic - `this.getClass()` will always return the actual subclass token.

Note also that I declared `Super` as `abstract` - this is (almost always) good practice to follow with base classes.

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately it doesn't really solve the problem I'm hoping to solve. I'm not sure there is an actual solution in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with out using static methods

```
public class Parent {
  public print(){
    System.err.println(this.getSimpleName());
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  public void main(String[] args) {
     Parent p = new Parent();
     p.print(); 
     Child c = new Child();
     c.print();
  }
}
```